# Create multiple instances of managed bean component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, multiple-instances, icefaces-3

Everything I've read about this up to this point leads me to believe that there isn't a clean way of doing this. Say we have an ace list component that we want to be reusable in a page. We have the following (i know you can't give the managedBean multiple names with annotations, but this is just to show what I am trying to do).

```
@ManagedBean(name="carListBean, truckListBean, suvListBean")
@CustomScoped(value="#{window}")
public class TestListBean {

    private List<Vehicle> dragFromList;
    private List<Vehicle> dragDestList;

    public TestListBean() {

    }

    public List<Vehicle> getDragFromList() {
        return dragFromList;
    }

    public List<Vehicle> getDragDestList() {
        return dragDestList;
    }

    public void setDragFromList(List<Vehicle> dragFromList) {
        this.dragFromList = dragFromList;
    }

    public void setDragDestList(List<Vehicle> dragDestList) {
        this.dragDestList = dragDestList;
    }

}

@ManagedBean(name="testSearchBean")
@RequestScoped
public class TestSearchBean {

   private VehicleService vehicleService;

   @ManagedProperty("#{carListBean}")
   TestListBean carListBean;

   @ManagedProperty("#{truckListBean}")
   TestListBean truckListBean;

   @ManagedProperty("#{suvListBean}")
   TestListBean suvListBean;

   private String year;
   private String color;

   public TestSearchBean() {
       vehicleService = new VehicleService();
   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       carListBean.setDragDestList(new ArrayList<Vehicle>());
       carListBean.setDragFromList(vehicleService.getVehicleList("car"));
       truckListBean.setDragDestList(new ArrayList<Vehicle>());
       truckListBean.setDragFromList(vehicleService.getVehicleList("truck"));
       suvListBean.setDragDestList(new ArrayList<Vehicle>());
       suvListBean.setDragFromList(vehicleService.getVehicleList("suv"));
   }

   // all getters and setters here...
```

i would then have the searchScreen.xhtml that would have 3 ace:list components displaying a list of trucks, cars and suvs.

is this possible to do in some way? also, is this bad design? i figured it would be cleaner to reuse a Managed ListBean rather than have almost identical code in 3 different classes (the only difference being the service call argument). any thoughts on this would be great. thanks! i'm hoping BalasC has some input on this.

Comment: You can do it in `faces-config.xml` by creating 3 `managed-bean` with different names.

Comment: @VasilLukach: You can also create a plain hashmap based bean which can contain any amount of instances of a class. The key  is the 'name' then. More flexible